# Bootstrap Modal Replace Placeholder

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, replace

I´ve already searched a while for this but i couldn´t figure out how to get it work. I am new to jQuery/AJAX and Bootstrap and i hope it is not to easy....

I have this Button in a loop

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#info" data-added="<?php if( strtotime($ecp_code->added) > strtotime('2000-01-01 01:00:00') ) { echo date('d.m.y H:i', strtotime($ecp_code->added)); } else { echo "-";} ?>" data-modified="<?php if( strtotime($ecp_code->changed) > strtotime('2000-01-01 01:00:00') ) { echo date('d.m.y H:i', strtotime($ecp_code->changed)); } else { echo "-";} ?>"><i class="fa fa-info" style="width:14px;"></i></button>
```

That´s the Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="info" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="infoLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                Informations
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Added: PLACEHOLDER
                Modified: PLACEHOLDER2
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>        
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#info').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
            var added = button.data('added');
            var modified = button.data('modified');

            var content = 'Added: ' + added + ' Modified: ' + modified + '';

            var modal = $(this);
            modal.find('.modal-body').text(content);
        });
    });
</script>
```

That´s working fine. It replaces the whole content from the modal-body.

---

But now i want that just a single word is replaced. PLACEHOLDER with the var added and PLACEHOLDER2 with the var modified. (It´s just an example)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#info').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
            var added = button.data('added');
            var modified = button.data('modified');
            var modal = $(this);
            var res = replace("PLACEHOLDER", (added));
            modal.find('.modal-body').text(res);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Something like this is not working.

One more Question: Do you know good resources where i can lern jQuery and AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert two new elements in the modal-body

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <label>Added:</label>
    <div id="Added"></div>
    <label>Modified:</label>    
    <div id="Modified"></div>
</div>

modal.find('.modal-body #Added').text(your content added);
```

And:

```
modal.find('.modal-body #Modified').text(your content modified);
```

If the content you are adding to those divs contains `html` tags you can better use `.html()` in place of `.text()`

Comment: Its working - thank you! A really good idea. But just out of interest: Is it possible to replace a single Word in a Modal?

Comment: You can replace like this content = content.replace(/ the_word/g, "other_word"); where the_word is the one you want to replace and other_word the replacement. Please mark this answer as answered. It is important for future users. Keep also in mind that the replace method will replace all the matching words.

Comment: Already marked as answer. :) When i use the replace i get the Error "Uncaught ReferenceError: replace is not defined".

content = content.replace(/ PLACEHOLDER1/g, added);
modal.find('.modal-body').text(content);

Comment: You are using this not in the correct way. `content` must be your response `content_added` in other words is the string where you want to make the replacement. In the replace function you set the string you want to replace and the word that replace it. Keep in mind that this will maybe fail if you use long strings of text